# из двух масивов дат в один php

Tags: php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]у меня есть два массива с датами

1 массив $period_data_form
2 массив $date_holidays

мне необходимо исключить в 1 массиве даты 2 массива

Подскажите пожалуйста как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом `array_diff`

```
array_diff($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
foreach ($period_data_form as $item){
    $key = false;
    $key = array_search($item, $date_holidays);
    if ($key != false) unset($period_data_form[$key]); 
}
```